# What XML is preferred for data transfer in comparison with other formats?

Tags: json, xml, csv, soap, data-transfer

I was going through data transmission and was wondering why XML is still in use?

Every source puts JSON and even CSV data format over XML, but from practice I can say that XML is still popular. Only reason that comes to mind is SOAP and its WS-security, which allows only XML. But even though every REST API prefers JSON, XML can still can be used.

What will be the key factor when choosing a format?

Comment: Three very good reasons 1) Every object has a label. 2) XML can have a schema to use to validate the xml. 3)  There is a specification that documents the xml format.

Comment: @jdweng: If you and Neeka (or one other party) would care to vote to reopen, I'd support you adding your comment as an answer.

Comment: **Reason to vote to reopen:** [My answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62449944/290085) provides objective perspective useful to OP and future readers.  I welcome other answers providing additional insights such as those listed by @jdweng, currently relegated to a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Because XML is a better fit for *documents* than JSON or CSV.

Current use of XML for data (as opposed to documents) is a relic from an earlier era when XML's use had been over-extended beyond its natural fit as a representation for documents.

Here are some useful current heuristics to guide your choice between CSV, XML, and JSON:

**Choose CSV if**

- Your data is tabular and you have to transfer it between relational databases or spreadsheets.

**Choose XML if**

- An industry standard XSD exists.
- You value more mature validation standard and tools.
- You need to transform the data to another XML form.  (XSLT is excellent for transformations.)
- Or, you have to represent mixed content (tags mixed within text).

**Choose JSON if**

- The closer fit to JavaScript is valuable to you or your callers.
- You prefer a lighter-weight solution.
- Or, the above **Choose XML if** reasons do not apply to you.